# Is macOS Sierra currently bug-free and stable to run Adobe programs?

Tags: macos

I'm thinking about updating to macOS Sierra, but I'm worried if there are still any bugs. Has anyone used it yet?

Comment: No OS is complete bug-free, but for my use, I haven't run into any major issues.

Comment: Just stay aware about your software, check if is compatible. My Illustrator 2014 wont open anymore... Apache + MySQL, I lost half a day to figure out how make them work properly again

Comment: Ouch, okay. Thanks @Vagner, I think that'll be an issue for me as well.

Comment: As IronCraftMan says, no OS is completely bug free. And Vagner is correct about checking software compatbility. One good place to start is at [Roaring Apps](http://roaringapps.com/). However, please keep in mind that if you have any critical software you rely on, you should check with the software publisher's website to confirm compatibility. Finally, it'd be good if you provided your Mac hardware details (model, RAM, etc) to properly answer this question. As it stands, we have no idea what Mac you want to install this on.

Comment: @Monomeeth - Thanks for providing that resource! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not bug free.  The question is whether its bugs matter for your particular needs.  To find that out, clone you current system to another partition, upgrade that to Sierra, and verify that the apps and external devices you require for your work all operate the way you need them too.